# search keyword from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
function _searchProductByName($name = "") {
    $query = $this->db
            ->select("S.*,CC.id as catId, CC.name as CatName")
            ->from("categories as S")
            ->join("categories as C",'C.id=S.parentid','LEFT')
            ->join("categories as CC",'CC.id=C.parentid','LEFT')
            ->where("S.order", 2)
            ->like("S.name", $name, 'both')
            ->order_by("S.name", 'asc')
            //->order_by('locate('.$name.', S.name) asc, S.name asc')
            ->get();

    return $query && $query->num_rows() ? $query->result() : [];
}
```

when my keywords is **lap** 
it gives results:

```
{
"status": true,
"response": [
    {
        "id": "834",
        "parentid": "46",
        "name": "Collapsible Wardrobes",
        "order": "2",
        "hasChild": "0",
        "icon": null,
        "created": "2018-01-15 15:01:45",
        "catId": "5",
        "CatName": "Home Furniture, Decor , Pets"
    },
    {
        "id": "936",
        "parentid": "51",
        "name": "Laptop Desks",
        "order": "2",
        "hasChild": "0",
        "icon": null,
        "created": "2018-01-15 15:01:45",
        "catId": "5",
        "CatName": "Home Furniture, Decor , Pets"
    },
    {
        "id": "936",
        "parentid": "51",
        "name": "mobile latptop",
        "order": "2",
        "hasChild": "0",
        "icon": null,
        "created": "2018-01-15 15:01:45",
        "catId": "5",
        "CatName": "Home Furniture, Decor , Pets"
    }
  ]
}
```

when i use after in place or both it gives only **Laptop Desks** result but i need when i search for lap it gives me result.

Laptop Desk and mobile laptops

the first data is **Collapsible Wardrobes** which contains **lap** but it is in between collapsible which i don't need how do i get this?

Comment: You could add % before and after name to allow for partial matches. IOW, ```'%'.$name.'%'```

Comment: @SloanThrasher i am using this by __both__ above are same what you said. but what i need mentioned above

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, especially this line. `when i use after in place or both it gives only Laptop Desks result but i need when i search for lap it gives me result.` - Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Cashbee   ->like("S.name", $name, 'both') in place of both when i use after it gives result names -- Laptop Desk only.  but when i search for __lap__ i need Laptop Desk and mobile latptop also.

Comment: well yes, this is the expected behaviour. So i guess what you want is to use `both` but remove 'collapsible wardrobes' from your result?

Comment: is "lap" the input that the user makes in a search bar?

Comment: @Cashbee yes i want what you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly (according to the comments)
a possible solution could be to look for a word following with a space or at the beginning such as

```
$query = $this->db
        ->select("S.*,CC.id as catId, CC.name as CatName")
        ->from("categories as S")
        ->join("categories as C",'C.id=S.parentid','LEFT')
        ->join("categories as CC",'CC.id=C.parentid','LEFT')
        ->where("S.order", 2)
        ->group_start()
            ->like('S.name', $name, 'after')
            ->or_like('S.name', ' '.$name, 'both')
        ->group_end()
        ->order_by("S.name", 'asc')
        //->order_by('locate('.$name.', S.name) asc, S.name asc')
        ->get();
```

this should output

```
SELECT `S`.*, `CC`.`id` AS `catId`, `CC`.`name` AS `CatName`
FROM `categories` AS `S`
LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `C` ON `C`.`id`=`S`.`parentid`
LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `CC` ON `CC`.`id`=`C`.`parentid`
WHERE `S`.`order` = 2 AND (`S`.`name` LIKE 'lap%' ESCAPE '!' OR `S`.`name` LIKE '% lap%' ESCAPE '!')
ORDER BY `S`.`name` ASC
```

Comment: it works but order_by not working. can you please show how to use order_by

Comment: what do you mean with *order_by* not working ? and on the other hand - you should open a new question because this one answered your specific problem

Comment: in the same question order_by() works but now when i put your query oreder by ASC not working. i need first keyword comes first

Comment: what do you get and what do you want because right now i can't understand how this should even affect the query ....

Comment: Laptop Desks first then mobile latptop it gives me opposite result

Comment: Sounds like you want you want a case-insensitive order by. use an order by on ```LCASE(`S`.`name`)```